# Reading input from stdin using scanf() in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, scanf

Assuming that the inputs are:

```
6 4
0 1 2 2 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0
```

6 and 4 are  width and height respectively.
What I used is:

```
scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);
```

Then I put the rest of the inputs in the 2D-array (board[height][width]) using for loops.
The problem is about validating the width and height.

When I input

```
6 4
0 1 2 2 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 0
```

one input is missed but it waits until one more number is entered. How can I manage this and make it to occur an error if lack of or too many inputs are being put?

Can someone help me out with this problem? Thanks!!

Comment: `scanf` returns a value. Check it, for starters.

Comment: Is your question to check if the given input for width and height are correct after creating the entire board? You could keep a counter while inserting values into the `board` and check if it's equal to `width * height`. However that'd be a naive check

Comment: I know if(scanf("%d %d", &width, &height) != 2) {} but 
6 4 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
also prints the output... Is there anyway to separate the width&height and the rest of the inputs by pressing an enter?

Comment: For example, I put 6 4 and press enter and then rest of the inputs, otherwise it should occur an error. So 6 4 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 should occur an error since even I dont press enter after 6 and 4, it prints the output.

Comment: The `scanf()` family of functions don't care about newlines; they're just white space to be consumed.  If you care about lines, read with `fgets()` and parse with `sscanf()`.  Note that the whole data set can be on one line as long as there are blanks between the numbers, or each number can be on a line on its own with an arbitrary number of blank lines between successive numbers.  You won't spot the difference with `scanf()`.

Comment: fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &width, &height); like this...?

Comment: It's an error if one value is missing, but does the input have to be `height` lines, or can the whole sequence for example be on one single line? That affects what checks you need to make.

Comment: I think the input I wrote, 6 and 4 need to be separated from the rest of the inputs...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gets`, `strtok` and `atoi` to get it done.

Following is complete working code. See [here](https://ideone.com/bhDhex) working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int w, h, i, j;
    char buffer[100];
    scanf("%d %d", &w, &h);
    int num[w][h];
    gets(buffer);
    for(i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        gets(buffer);
        char *token = strtok(buffer, " ");
        for(j =w; j && token; j--)
        {
            num[i][w-j] = atoi(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        if(j)
        {
            //Do what you wish to do on error
            printf("\nError!!! %d inputs are missing\n", j);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j<w; j++)
            printf("%d ", num[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```